# Practical Application of divmod() function in python, or how can we use divmod() other than just calculating / and %?

Tags: python, built-in, divmod

I just want to know how can we use divmod() function for some practical application other than just calculating / and %. I want to know if yes, then how can we use divmod function to prove if a number is prime or not. This would be a perfect practical application of divmod()

Comment: It *exists* for calculating the quotient and remainder.  Presumably it's more efficient than performing the operations independently.

Comment: I want to know a program where i can use it to calculate something or find something, other than just writing divmod and calculating it.

Comment: @AyushSaxena Say you're wanting to convert an unsigned integer to a string. You'd want to loop until the integer is 0, performing divmod on it: assign the result of the division to the integer, print the result of the mod, as it's the digit.

Answer (score 4):

One application (don't know whether it is "practical" enough) is to determine the digits comprising an integer:

```
n = 12345
while n:
    n, r = divmod(n, 10)
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Here the quotient is assigned back to `n` effectively stripping off the last digit which is available in the remainder, `r`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use it for example for changing the base of the number. For example, for base 5:

```
>>> x = 3456
>>> res = ""
>>> while x != 0:
...   x, m = divmod(x, 5)
...   res = str(m) + res
...
>>> print(res)
102311
>>> int(res, 5)
3456
```